# Mapbox cannot load newer version of style

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

on my website, I use detault Mapbox Outdoors style - generated it like two years ago. All works well, but recently I noticed that Outdoor styles created later contain much more data (mountains and so on) - it seems that the style was updated in the meantime.

So I created a new Outdoor style and it contains all that extra data I need. But the map doesnt load with the newly created style. This is the error when I try to display the style

```
Error: [1]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string) | (boolean, boolean) | (null, null), but found (value, number) instead.
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? The old style works, only the new one returns error. Could it be caused by the fact that I also changed Mapbox version from 0.42 to 1.5?

Thank you